# Верно ли отсутствие запятой?

Tags: запятые

Верно ли отсутствие запятой: «Его забрали прежде чем ему исполнился год»? Типа его забрали еще до того, как исполнился год. Или поставить запятую перед «прежде»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Его забрали, прежде чем ему исполнился год.**
- **Его забрали прежде, чем ему исполнился год.**

По общему правилу в вашем случае подходит первый вариант, но если вам требуется сделать ударение на *"прежде"*, не противоречит правилам и второй вариант.

Подробнее [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_628).

Comment: Да, согласен, возможно разделение составного союза.

Comment: А если не требуется сделать ударение на "прежде", второй вариант противоречит правилам? Логическая ошибка. Что-то со структурой.

Comment: @oleed да, если ударение стоит на "забрали", то запятая после "прежде" — ошибка.

Comment: Не так получается. Логические ударения в тексте не отмечаются. Если не требуется сделать ударение на "прежде", второй вариант тоже не противоречит правилам. Второй вариант в любом случае правилам не противоречит. Бывает, когда хотели одно, а сделали другое, но тоже правильное. Да, они ошиблись, но правила не нарушили.

Comment: @oleedd там по ссылке есть конкретные правила, в каких случаях составной союз расчленяется, а в каких нет. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3 "Автор желает подчеркнуть, что на первую часть составного союза падает логическое ударение" —это один из пунктов правила.

Comment: Я про вашу формулировку, а не про правила. Хотим ударение на "забрали", а ставим запятую после "прежде". Получается второй вариант, он правилам не противоречит. Задуманные логические ударения корректор не увидит. Пунктуация либо противоречит правилам, либо нет, вне ударений. Либо так можно, либо так нельзя. Задуманные логические ударения не влияют на корректность пунктуации, то уже касается корректности реализации.

Comment: @oleedв я вообще написал в том смысле, что "если вам потребуется сделать ударение на "прежде" [то есть переместить запятую], то это не будет ошибкой.

Comment: Но второй вариант пунктуационно корректен сам по себе, вне зависимости от того, куда автор ставит ударения. Просто там есть разговорное упрощение, которым очень интересовался и которое исследовал, поэтому решил не проходить мимо.

Comment: Просто звучит так, что второй вариант противоречит правилам, но если требуется "ударение", то уже не противоречит. Кстати, оба правила общие. Второе не из исключений. Например: "он пришёл, потому что" и "он пришёл потому, что" имеют равные права на существование. Просто второй вариант более книжный.